# Root Terminal command to kill or stop a service?

Tags: tasker, task-management, processes

The latest [LiveView Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview&hl=en) for my device keeps appearing on the status bar even if the LiveView device isn't connected. Since I can't find any means to disable this behavior, I want to create a fix for myself via Tasker. I made it so that the LiveView process is killed when the device disconnects. However, although this successfully kills the app, after a few seconds or minutes, it starts up again and sits on the notification bar like before. I suppose this is a countermeasure against Task Killers of sort.

This is the next approach I'm taking, using a terminal command to kill or stop a service fully. I'm going to run this command in Tasker in replacement of the process kill method.

Another thing I found to work is to go to Settings > Apps > LiveView > Force Close. So if Force Close is do-able via terminal, that would be nice too.

This is all on a rooted ST17i, running MiniCMSandwich Lite ROM (ICS).

Answer (score 5):

Your suggested approach would have the same result: a few seconds later, the app would be back. Tasker kills it again. Start at the beginning. This vicious circle will certainly help you drain your battery faster -- but nothing else.

Two possible solutions would include either to uninstrall the app, or to disable the "listener" it established to get started on certain events. The latter can be done by e.g. [Autorun Manager PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun.pro) (yes, this requires the Pro version):

[image: AutoRun Manager]

Though there are similar solutions available, and I tested some of them, *AutoRun Manager* seemed to be the best: It's faster than most of the others, and finds more intents than many others. But as the app also warns: if you disable too many (or the wrong) listeners, the (disabled) app may start misbehaving. To get around that, a new version of this app (coming soon) will implement profiles to switch between (so you could e.g. have one "disabled" profile, and one "enabled"), and also allows for the third option below. (Before anybody asks: No, I'm not the developer -- I just happened to suggest this feature to him, and he approved it).

A third option, which will soon be available with *AutoRun Manager*, already is available with [Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro): Freeze the app in question when not needing it, and unfreeze it when you want it. *Titanium Backup* even offers to create a widget to switch between both states -- but you need one widget per app.

Comment: Tasker can also freeze apps in conjunction with Secure Settings plugin

Answer (score 2):

you can execute: `pm disable "packagename"` to fully hibernate

apply `pm enable "packagename"` to enable again

Some info & examples (click images to show larger variant):

[image: my device] [image: freezer] [image: unfreezer]

In case `pm disable` / `pm enable` seems not to work on your device, try `pm hide` / `pm unhide` instead, which was introduced with Android 5. Some Kitkat devices even used `pm block` / `pm unblock`.

[Disable vs hide](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128949/93921)

Comment: Ah, thanks! Maybe then it should rather be `pm hide`, depending on the Android version? AFAIK it should be that since Lollipop, also [see here](/q/128949/16575).

Comment: Thanks! I just added a little formatting and a hint to the `pm hide` command, then countered the negative vote someone left. Will cleanup the (now upsolete) comments then.