# pm hide VS pm disable -- the identity crisis

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, command-line

What's the need of `pm disable` when `pm hide` already does its job?

I've compiled some information based on my search and research: click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BICvN.png) to see the table (*edited*).

As you can see, `pm hide` can achieve what `pm disable` can, *but without needing root access*. Also, based on my tests, I've reached the conclusion that when `pm hide` is performed, unlike `pm disable`, no matter what, the app will not be loaded in the memory again.

I opine that *hide* descended from *block*. *Block* was first introduced in [KitKat 4.4.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r0.7/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java), remained till [Android L Preview](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-l-preview_r2/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java) and was later superseded by *hide* in Android 5.0.0. It is not clear to me what lead to renaming of *block* to *hide* and why was it needed?

Regardless, if somebody without root access can achieve the functionality of *disable*, then why does *disable* exists at all?

Furthermore, why does *hide* exists? If *hide* was built supposedly to help users to  get rid of anything they want, without un-installation and without rooting the device, then in the GUI we should be having a relevant option, but [we've got only the disable option](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122643/96277).

Intertwine questions:

- What are the merits and demerits of them, excluding those  noted in my question?
- Why both of them exists and to what or whom do they serve?
- Is it technically true that *hide* surpasses the functionality of *disable* and ***can truly disable any app***, when executed on it?
- ***New***: Given findings of Andrew T. and my tests shown in the table, is component shown in *hide*'s usage an error or have I failed to understand latter's usage?

  For historical purposes: *hide*'s usage as of now is shown as

  ```
    pm hide [--user USER_ID] PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
  ```

**Note:** The question does not, in any fashion, seeks unsubstantiated opinion but straight to-the-point answer(s). *If you must write an opinion, make sure to back it up using credible and technical sources with sound reasoning to make distinction between what is technical and real and what is speculative.*

---

Tests performed on Carbon ROM (Android 5.1.1) and COS12 (Android 5.0.2) for OnePlus One.

Comment: Probably the biggest difference is, you can *disable per-app component* (activity, service, broadcast receiver, content provider) without disabling the app itself, but you can only *hide the whole application*. The `pm` usage is slightly confusing for `hide`, but the underlying code only process the whole package, not the component. In other word, [`hide` is temporary `uninstall -k`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#L4341).

Comment: That is interesting info. Now that you've mentioned this info, I would test and report whether `hide` can disable a component or not. Its usage seems a copy of `disable`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r29/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1814

Comment: That's why it's misleading; [`runSetEnabledSetting()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1681) checks for component name, but [`runSetHiddenSetting()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1730) only checks for package name. Not sure if it can hide component in the future though.

Comment: @AndrewT., thanks you for the information. My tests have shown results in accordance with your information. Please see the revised question including the edited table for further info. If possible at the moment, consider posting a formal answer.

Comment: I'd guess, since disable required root so would enable. Having app disabled would then give better guarantees that no malicious app would be able to enable it.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as Andrew...

Comment: References: [Introduces a new "blocked" state](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/655d0e2029e6ae77a47e922dce4c4989818b8dd1) and [Rename `setApplicationBlocked` to `setApplicationHidden`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e5bcff624fb58b6f95be8ddff7f5b6b3bf5d19c7)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to comment yet.. This is not an answer... more like... information:

pm hide does [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#6431)

pm disable does [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#setApplicationEnabledSetting(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) and **if** it can find the component name then [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)).

I can see how some people may have thought that pm hide would do an uninstall.

ex.  If you run this command after a pm hide

```
diff <(adb shell pm list packages -u) <(adb shell pm list packages)
```

You'll see your hidden package.  -u is a list of previously uninstalled packages.

These pm commands below all invoke androids Intent class.

```
pm hide <package>
pm unhide <package>
pm enable <package>
pm disable <package>
```

This command below:

```
pm hide <package>
```

invokes:

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED.
```

This below command:

```
pm unhide <package>
```

invokes:

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED.
```

pm disable and pm enable both invoke:

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED.
```

Thanks @Irfan Latif for the corrections.  I can verify what he was saying.  Under Android Settings:  If you look at installed apps, even after pm hide, you can still see the app is installed.  Interestingly, with pm disable, the app disappears from installed apps.  These commands don't seem to create any obvious filesystem changes.

These directories:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/
/data/data
```

and other misc directories...

One possible hypothesis... Maybe its best practice to always call both commands to disable any package:

```
pm disable <package>;pm hide <package>
```

Comment: `pm hide` is available on Android 9 and hiding an app doesn't uninstall it. All (or at least some partial) data is intact after `unhide`.

Comment: I removed my Android 6 reference I removed it just seconds before you posted your comment, but thanks for that.  According to this dude its the same as uninstall -k.  https://github.com/blackbbc/Evil-Hide/blob/master/README_en.md  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173985/3066563

Comment: `pm uninstall -k` deletes `/data/app/<pkg>` directory entirely, `pm hide` does not.

Comment: But still your answer/information doesn't answer, at least, the first line of the question.

Comment: Correct.  So do you think it should be deleted then?