# How can I wholly delete Apps like News Republic, Zoe Video Editor?

Tags: htc-desire

Please see below screenshot. My grandma doesn't want any speck of 'Zoe Video Editor', not even "the factory version". But her HTC Desire 825 doesn't let her delete it. She hasn't rooted her phone.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are system apps then she won't be able to delete them unless the device is rooted.
With no root, you are left with disabling them. Settings -> Apps, select the app, then click on Disable.

If you are unable to disable them via the settings as indicated above, then try disabling them via adb as shown in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182123/247431).

Comment: I upvoted, and thanks! I removed that bracketed assumption because you're correct!