# Cant delete system files on rooted phone

Tags: file-management, system

I'm using zarchiver as a file managing app on my rooted phone... I cant delete some specific app folders in

/system/app              even though I remounted it as rewritable.... in rewritable it will show delete option but when you choose it it wont actually delete it....

context: I want to delete some APK folder of some bloat wares like google or You tube app

Comment: Deleting a system app from system partition will not regain any storage on your user data partition. Therefore you can simply disable the system app: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182123/2241

Comment: Based on the description [ZArchiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver) does not seem to be able to use root permissions, hence it can not delete a system app. An app have to be explicitly developed to use root permissions.

Comment: Link2SD is also good app manager, can freeze apps etc (without actually having 2nd SD Card partition)

Comment: hmmm actually my main purpose on rooting it is to actually remove unnecessary files to free more storage... any tips on where are those useless files and how to delete them

Comment: ZArchiver can use root permissions. its just that it seems to fail to use that granted root permission