# How can be deleted the com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim?

Tags: applications, adb, system-apps, bloatware

I have been told this is a compatibility test suite, but it is safe to delete? if so, how can be deleted from the device?

Comment: It is a [system app](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup) (see CTS shim package heading). Why do you want to delete it? Are you experiencing symptoms of a malware on your device? In my device I see that I can disable the app. Is that not enough?

Comment: If you don't get a Disable option or if you want to uninstall it see my answer. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182123/96277 A system app is never truly uninstalled without root access. It would be reinstated once you factory reset the device.

Comment: @Firelord, Im trying to uninstall bloarware, and I dont know what is this.

Comment: Bloatware that does not get updates via Play Store and that is not running in background does no harm. If you disable it or delete it with root permissions you can do harm to your device. Therefore if you don't know something better don't touch it.