# How to enable and disable app using LADB?

Tags: adb, disable-app

So far, I only could find this related [discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182118/314204) from this site regarding disabling app on android by ADB, but I'm using LADB app and confirm whether these commands are correct or not since the discussion didn't mention anything about re-enabling the app.

```
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 <package name>

adb shell pm enable-user --user 0 <package name>
```

This is the app I am going to use:

[image]

Will it work just like when I disable or enable app through *settings*? The app I wanna disable is Facebook, by the way. On my old phone android 8.1, it has disable feature, but idk why my phone with android 11 doesn't have this feature. Anyway, are those commands safe to try? I'm not familiar with Android shell whatever, I only thought it would be wise to ask here first before I test it.

Comment: Facebook is a third party app so even if it comes pre-installed as system app you should be able to disable it in apps sections of Android settings.

Comment: An app disabled using shell is not listed in Settings app at all. You would have to use a third-party app to list disabled apps. As for LADB, its Play Store page gives instructions to make it connect to wireless adb. If you follow the instructions correctly this app should give you access to shell (aka adb shell). After that, you can run your `pm disable... ` commands.