# How to uninstall/disable system apps on Fire HD 8?

Tags: system-apps, disable-app, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I want to uninstall or disable system apps on my Amazon Fire HD 8 2017. How can I do this? The FireOS version in "System Updates" menu is 5.6.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method to disable system apps on Fire HD 8 2017, on your FireOS version. (Discovered by myself, actually :D) You can see that XDA thread [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/hd8-hd10/general/a-t3820744). To battle possible link rot I'll also describe it here too.

1. I'm not going to add a guide on how to install ADB here, [this page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/connecting-adb-to-device.html) by Amazon explains it thoroughly, so you can follow it.
2. Download the APK attached in post #2, or if the link is broken download it from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=com.amazon.unifiedsharefacebook.apk). You can install it with ADB if you know how to, or just install it as you install other APK files.
3. This is one of most important but most ignored steps. **Reboot your tablet.**
4. The Amazon page explains how to run `adb` commands. Run these commands in order.

`adb shell`

`run-as com.amazon.unifiedsharefacebook`

5. Run `pm hide` on every app you want to hide. (You might be thinking the difference between hide and disable. `pm hide` vs. `pm disable` was analyzed on [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128949/pm-hide-vs-pm-disable-the-identity-crisis).) You can check the package name of the app you want to install by "App Inspector". You can download and install it from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bg.projectoria.appinspector&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dapp%20inspector&pcampaignid=APPU_1_ntssXL34HYj7rQGDn7D4Aw) and check the package name of the app you want to remove.

Example: `pm hide com.amazon.kindle`

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GLb_1xIWz1uGVEJEikwEaqRF0rhMVQI5vlMQcUm6m8U/htmlview) are all the apps that are safe to remove. Removing any other all could cause unexpected bugs.

Good luck!

Comment: it worked and improved speed so much. thank you!!!