# What EXACTLY does "pm uninstall" do on an unrooted Android 9.0 device?

Tags: adb, rooting, uninstallation, disable-app, tee

There seems to be confusion regarding the behavior of `pm uninstall` from the ADB shell, see also [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/pm-uninstall-k.4427021/) and [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-pm-disable-wheres-it-store-the-list.2379517/).

**Question:** What configuration files does `pm uninstall` write to, is it `/data/system/packages.xml`, `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` or both? Are there any additional files?

Note: This questions specifically concerns the behavior of `pm uninstall`, not `pm disable`. Furthermore, it concerns the behavior on *unrooted* devices.

Motivation: Uninstalling the wrong apps doing `pm uninstall` can result in a soft-brick/boot loop. Therefore, reversing the effects of `pm uninstall` can be the easiest way out of such problem, especially if other methods risk wiping data that needs to be rescued.

Comment: I think the question title should better be "What EXACTLY does pm uninstall do when uninstalling a system app". Because on regular apps it doesn't matter if your device is rooted or not, the app would simply be uninstalled. Also on system apps I don't think pm would be able to uninstall (delete) it even with root permissions.

Comment: ...this bit of information should actually be part of an answer. Also, the solution should be specific to Android 9.0 or at least include it.

Comment: I don't think that somebody exactly has the answer to this question. But you can try it out yourself. get yourself a rooted emulator, uninstall a system app as you did on your Samsung phone and then compare the xml files before and after uninstalling the system app. A possible emulator for that purpose would be Genymotion as it provides images for different Android versions.

Comment: curious about what is the difference between `pm` [block](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/enable-and-disable-system-apps-via-adb) vs [hide](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205961/how-to-uninstall-disable-system-apps-on-fire-hd-8) vs [disable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128949/pm-hide-vs-pm-disable-the-identity-crisis) vs [disable-user](https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-system-app-bloatware-android) vs [uninstall](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access) for system apps

Comment: As I understand, Android is open source and written entirely in C. I don't have sufficient command of C, but would it be possible to find definite answers in regard to function behavior by searching the source code (https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject)?

Comment: yes, homework for someone with too many free time hehe.. actually it's [java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#173)/kotlin ;)