# Cron job over adb possible?

Tags: adb

I'm trying to use my phone less. I've managed successfully to remove apps via adb. My question is if it's possible to have apps disable/remove via their package names over adb, and then reinstated on the device at certain times of the day.

So for say the hours 9am to 5pm Chrome app would be completely removed and not on the device, then after 5 it's there again.

I'm not wanting app timers or the app being disabled but app icon still visible. I'm after the full removal followed later in the day by it's full revival. Thanks :)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128949
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747880

Comment: IMHO the question is formulated "too specific". You explicitly ask for cron but Android has no cron daemon by default. It would be better to ask how to schedule periodic tasks on Android. In the latter case you would get answers for apps like Tasker.