# How can I rephrase: adb shell "pm block com.sec.knox.bridge" to work in an Android 10 phone?

Tags: adb, samsung, samsung-knox

Hope I am asking the right kind of question. I recently gained from my father a brand new phone his company gave him shortly before his retirement. They gave it to him knowing he was leaving and were trying to be nice. However the phone was still attached to the security settings of the company, including being tied to a Intune Company Portal app, I believe via Knox. Long story short I managed to uninstall that app after eventually being able to revoke its admin app permissions (previously it kept reinstalling itself). I am now trying to put the final nail in the coffin to make sure it can't come back to haunt me.

I have managed to connect my s10 to ADB on my computer and a site I found that helped me with some of the above gave a list of commands to remove Knox. They all follow the format in the title, which to repeat here is

`adb shell "pm block com.sec.knox.bridge"`

however the return is `Unknown command: block`

I imagine this was a fix for a previous version using old nomenclature. So my question is how do I correct the above syntax for that statement to do its job?

Cheers,
Shane

Comment: Hello. It is a good thing to always mention the link from where you are trying to follow the instructions so that we can evaluate and advise you whether the instructions are correct or not. For example, that pm block command is way, way too old. It is supposed to work only for Android Kitkat versions. Replace it with `pm hide` or `pm disable --user 0` followed by the package name. Do know that all of this would work as long as you don't do a factory reset. Once you reset, you'd have to repeat the cycle.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I will post more succinctly next time. The source for this particular solution is [here](https://www.androidinfotech.com/disable-samsung-knox-bloatware-apps/?unapproved=22524&moderation-hash=b0bcbdda1e20a6fc48dda2101db17e98#comment-22524) and links to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_SG-8WLw2lEnyuROX1ybClNyEhQPTNHiD7LYQqWcVis/edit#gid=0) for those command lines. I will attempt those commands and report back, cheers!

Comment: Further information regarding `pm block`, `pm hide`, and `pm disable`: [pm hide VS pm disable — the identity crisis](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128949/44325)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Firelord, use `pm disable --user 0` instead of `pm block`. `pm block` is deprecated (not exist of new versions of `pm`). if you have an error with `disable` then the application still device admin or the package name is not `com.sec.knox.bridge`.

**Check if the App is device admin**

```
adb shell dumpsys device_policy | grep knox
```

If the command output a result, then the application still device admin.

To be sure that the package name is `com.sec.knox.bridge`:

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep knox
```